# How to pass same String value from adapter to two different activities

Tags: java, android

I have an TicketAdapter class in onClick method I'm passing a String value (i.e `ticket.getId()`) where ticket is my pojo class) to `TicketDetailActivity` class, I also want to pass same value to one more activity i.e `SaveTicketDetailActivity` class

```
public class TicketAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
protected List<Ticket> tickets;

public void onClick(View v) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TicketDetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("com.qurater.csr.ticket.id", ticket.getId());
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_detail, R.anim.stay_in_place_detail);
}
```

Here as soon as I click when intent is fired I'm getting the value (i.e `ticket.getId()`)in `TicketDetailActivity` class.

Now I want same value to get as an reference in `SaveTicketDetailActivity`.class
I want this value as I'm sending some string data to the server the URL needs id and the data.
Thanks

Comment: you want to move in TicketDetailActivity.class class right? but from which class you want to go there ?

Comment: Why you create an activity for syncing? you can just just create an AsyncTask instance and pass the context and other arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

I can hardly imagine a scenario when the data needs to be passed to two activities in parallel. Maybe you can pass the data into `TicketDetailActivity` and from there pass it to `SaveTicketDetailActivity` if needed? Furthermore, using entirely new activity for the purpose of sending data to server seems an overkill. You got two better options:

1. If the data needs to be synced once its details are shown - add this logic to `TicketDetailActivity` in `onCreate()` (the simplest approach is to use `AsyncTask`)
2. If you want to implement Sync button in `SaveTicketDetailActivity` and sync the data when the button is pressed - this is bad user experience. A better design is to have this button in `TicketDetailActivity`.

Said that, if you still want to share a small amount of data between multiple activities, your best option is to use `SharedPreferences`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) for short tutorial.